# Importing psf in eclipse issue?

Tags: eclipse, svn, import

I get this error while I'm trying to import this : http://www.jppf.org/private/svn-trunk-projectSet.psf into eclipse.

```
Building workspace has encountered a problem error occurred during the build
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Checkstyle Builder' on project 'admin'.
Fileset from project "admin" has no valid check configuration.
Fileset from project "admin" has no valid check configuration.
Fileset from project "admin" has no valid check configuration.
Fileset from project "admin" has no valid check configuration.
```

Any suggestions what does it mean ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This error means that your Eclipse project contains a `.checkstyle` configuration file which points to a non-existing Checkstyle configuration entry.

If you don't want to use Checkstyle you could simply delete the `.checkstyle` file.

If you want to use Checkstyle you should provide a valid location under Project -> Properties -> Checkstyle.